# Connect to amazon rds SQL server through spoofed ip address

Tags: server, mysql, spoofing

I'm using amazon MySQL server and grant only my server IP to connect to the database, the question is can someone else access to the database through spoofed IP address and MySQL server credentials?

Comment: No, you cannot have 2-way communication with a host when you spoof your IP

Comment: *"No, you cannot have 2-way communication with a host when you spoof your IP"* @schroeder 's well you could spoof to a "hacked" box assuming you succesfully spoofed a IP on the TCP protocol which is very hard to do.